# Selenium, findelement, the entire <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css, selenium, xpath

I need to find element from a web page containing the word "Produktgewicht"

This is the code am using to find the element :

```
String Weight=wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Produktgewicht')]")).getText();
```

This is the source code of the web page :

```
<li>
    <b>
        Produktgewicht inkl. Verpackung:
    </b>
     6 Kg
</li>
```

The output for my code is **"Produktgewicht inkl. Verpackung:"**

But I want the entire `<li>`

This is my desired output **"Produktgewicht inkl. Verpackung: 6 Kg"**

I tried even

```
String Weight=wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Produktgewicht')]/following::li")).getText();
```

But it gives me the next `<li>`

Please help me out.....
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what it the `<ul class = ` equal to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//li[contains(., 'Produktgewicht')]
```

The above should return `<li>` that contains text 'Produktgewicht', no matter how deep the text nested within the `<li>`. Contrasts this with `*[contains(text(), 'Produktgewicht')]` which tests *first direct child* text node only.

`/following::li` which you tried didn't work because `<li>` is not following the previously matched `<b>` element, it is parent of the `<b>` instead :

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Produktgewicht')]/parent::li
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot, this method worked great....
My next question is, in some places the same details are mentioned as tables
This is the source code :

`<tr class="size-weight">
 <td class="label">
    Artikelgewicht
 </td>
 <td class="value">
    15 Kg
 </td>
</tr>
}`
your suggestion is working great for `<li>`
. But Is there a common way to pull `<td>` aswell as `<li>` ?
Because, I want to pull this **15 Kg** from this `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
element.all(by.css('li')).get(0).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath can be fairly simple:

```
//li[b[contains(.,'Produktgewicht')]]/text()
```

This should take entire text in given *li element*. You can also make also additional selection to mark **Produktgewicht** or **6 Kg** by adding the index value behind the xpath, f.e.:

```
//li[b[contains(.,'Produktgewicht')]]/text()[0]
//li[b[contains(.,'Produktgewicht')]]/text()[1]
```

First will mark the **Produktgewicht inkl. Verpackung:** and the second one will mark **6 Kg** text value